# jQuery AJAX: Posting serialized form data with $.post() does not achieve the same result as $.ajax()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was trying post data into a source by sending form's data using the jQuery's shorthand method `jQuery.post()` but I am not capable to achieve the same result as using the full blue-print for posting with `jQuery.ajax()`.

Please find below the scripts that I've used for my findings:

### Using $.post():

```
jQuery.post(
    "/full-path-to-service",
    {   cache: false, 
        data: jQuery(submittingForm).serialize(), 
        _: jQuery.now() },
    null,
    "json"
).done(function(data) {
  // Response handling
});
```

### Using $.ajax():

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/full-path-to-service",
    data: jQuery(submittingForm).serialize(),
    dataType: "json",
    _: jQuery.now()
}).done(function(data) {
    // Response handling
});
```

While I was able to receive a successful response from the server, the service seemed to be not being fired for not receiving the information previously sent serialized in the POST request.

Sniffing the information being sent to the service I was able to confirm that the information is parsed incorrectly while using `jQuery.post`.

Please find the differences below:

[image]

Is there any reasing for `jQuery.post()` not sending the information in the same way as using a blue-print for posting with `jQuery.ajax()`?

Comment: You are using the `jQuery.post()` function incorrectly. Check the documentation for proper usage: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Answer (score 1):

The second argument for `post()` is the data object (or string) you wish to pass. You are attempting to pass it the configuration object for `ajax()`.

`post()` is not `ajax()` and doesn't support the same level of customisation. It is designed to be much simpler. Use `ajax()` if you want to set all the options.

> Is there any reasing for jQuery.post() not sending the information in the same way as using a blue-print for posting with jQuery.ajax()?

Yes. It is a *simple* shorthand for common use cases.